# How do I interpret the given classification report?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, random-forest, model-evaluations

The given classification report was obtained from running a Random Forest binary classifier on the test data. There is huge class imbalance in the training data.
How do I interpret the given classification report showing very high values for one particular label?

```
            precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.98      1.00      0.99     35050
      1       0.98      0.72      0.83      1982
  total       0.98      0.98      0.98     37032
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. You could've found your answer on the documentation (https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/classification_report.html)

Answer (score 2):

Precision is the proportion of predictions of that class that are true. So 98% of the predictions for each of your classes are actually of the predicted class, and 2% are actually of the opposite class. Recall is the proportion of the true positives that are identified as such. This means that your model is correctly identifying 100% of the class 0s, but only 72% of the class 1s.

F1-Score is a kind of average of the two; it's an attempt to provide a unified figure of the model's performance, but personally I consider it less useful than the separate figures. It's calculated via the formula `2 x ((precision x recall) / (precision + recall))`.

Wikipedia's pages on these metrics are comprehensive:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score